# Keras model evaluation shows a TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not iterable for mnist dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, google-colaboratory

I just got started with keras, and I tried to build a model for the `mnist` dataset in the `keras.datasets`

Here's my initial code:

```
import tensorflow as tf

(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()
```

Then, I defined a model:

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential()

model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28,28)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation = tf.nn.relu))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation = tf.nn.softmax))

model.compile(loss = 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='rmsprop')
model.fit(train_images, train_labels, epochs=10)
```

I tried this model using `model.compile(loss = 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='rmsprop')` and the model just trained fine

Later, I tried to evaluate the model:

```
loss, accuracy = model.evaluate(test_images, test_labels)
print('Accuracy on the test set: '+str(accuracy))
```

and it showed the following ***error***:

```
10000/10000 [==============================] - 0s 50us/step
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-68-7ccd830be0cb> in <module>()
----> 1 loss, accuracy = model.evaluate(test_images, test_labels)
      2 print('Accuracy on the test set: '+str(accuracy))

TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not iterable
```

But, when I try to make predictions on the test_images by using `predictions = model.predict(test_images)`, it works fine.

I'm using google colab to code.
Please Help!

Comment: I don't see your model.fit() method.

Comment: I'm sorry, I've got it in the code but I forgot to include it in the post

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your model has no metrics as a result of lack of metrics parameter of your [model.compile()](https://keras.io/models/model/)

> **Compile**
>
> compile(optimizer, loss=None, **metrics=None,** loss_weights=None,
> sample_weight_mode=None, weighted_metrics=None, target_tensors=None)

call, thus as per the [documentation](https://keras.io/models/model/) :

> **Returns**
>
> Scalar test loss (if the model has a single output and **no metrics**) or
> list of scalars (if the model has multiple outputs and/or metrics).
> The attribute model.metrics_names will give you the display labels for
> the scalar outputs.

Keras model `evaluate()` returns only loss.

So if you alter your code:

```
model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'], optimizer='rmsprop')
```

you can get **accuracy** too.

Comment: It worked for me, but there's one slight correction. You've got to pass 'accuracy' as a list element to matrices; that is, metrics=['accuracy'] instead of just metrics='accuracy'

Comment: @SurajSJain Yes, thank you, excellent comment, as in the in the documentation I linked above, can be read. I missed it, sorry, will update my answer.